# Updating Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB

Tags: windows, tar

I was wondering if someone could help me figure out how to update Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB. Specifically, I am wanting to get the tar command that is in the more recent builds of Windows 10. I have 2016 and

Comment: So you want to upgrade your LTSB version to a regular one? Just start the setup program of the version you want to upgrade to. Note that the default language of upgrade version must be identical to the one of your system, otherwise the setup program refuses to take-over the old user settings and data and installed applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering if someone could help me figure out how to update Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB.

If you want to upgrade the `Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSC` to `Windows 10 Enterprise 2019 LTSC` you would need the appropriate license.

Since `Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSC` only recieves cumaltive updates, you would have to have a `Windows 10 Enterprise 2019 LTSC` ISO, in order to upgrade `Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSC` to `Windows 10 Enterprise 2019 LTSC`.

> Specifically, I am wanting to get the tar command that is in the more recent builds of Windows 10.

Before you perform that upgrade.  You should verify that `Windows 10 Enterprise 2019 LTSC` which is based on Windows 10 Enterprise version 1809 actually supports the command you are interested in.

**Since this version was introduce with Windows 10 version 1803, `Windows 10 Enterprise 2019 LTSC` should support the command, but LTSC versions of Windows 10 Enterprise do not always come with the same features as other editions.**

If for whatever reason, the command is not supported by `Windows 10 Enterprise 2019 LTSC`, then you will have to wait until `Windows 10 Enterprise 202X LTSC` is released, since that would be the next LTSC version that will be released.

> The Long Term Servicing Channel was previously called the Long Term Servicing Branch (LTSB). All references to LTSB are changed in this article to LTSC for consistency, even though the name of previous versions might still be displayed as LTSB.

While I suppose you could migrated to Windows 10 Enterprise version 1903, your licensing rights, might not include that particular version.  **If you are not the System Administrator for this particular system you should not attempt to make any changes to it.**

Source:

- [Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/ltsc/)
- [How To Use Tar On Windows 10](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/use-tar-on-windows-10/)

Comment: I would have loved to verify if `Windows 10 Enterprise 2019 LTSC` actually supported the command you are talking about, but you didn't provide enough information, to understand what command you are actually talking about.  **So I was unable to do research on that topic.**

Comment: The command is actually `tar` so there was nothing else to mention. Thank you for your help.